# iOS: Print Image within text to iMZ320 printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, zebra-printers

I use iZM320 printer to print a receipt like this:

https://gyazo.com/67aa41cf2f8d392f516494f64cde4d01

I use code:

1) Printing string (it worked)

```
-(BOOL)printReportAsOneJobUsingNSString:(id<NSObject,ZebraPrinter>)printer withString:(NSMutableString*)fullLabel {   
    NSError *error = nil;  

    long blockSize = 256;  
    long totalSize = fullLabel.length;  
    long bytesRemaining = totalSize;  

    while (bytesRemaining > 0) {  
        long bytesToSend = MIN(blockSize, bytesRemaining);  
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, bytesToSend);  

        NSString *partialLabel = [fullLabel substringWithRange:range];  

        [[printer getToolsUtil] sendCommand:partialLabel error:&error];  

        bytesRemaining -= bytesToSend;  

        [fullLabel deleteCharactersInRange:range];  

    }  

    return (error == nil);  
}
```

2) Print image

```
if (_printImage) {  
    id<GraphicsUtil, NSObject> graphicsUtil = [printer getGraphicsUtil];  
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  
        NSError *error = nil;  
        [graphicsUtil printImage:[_printImage CGImage] atX:_posX atY:_posYwithWidth:_printImage.size.width withHeight:_printImage.size.height andIsInsideFormat:NOerror:&error];  
    });  
}
```

But I don't know how to combine these function to print the receipt that I want.
Can you help me, please.

Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine - separate.

Take the first printing string and separate it into two. With the first half being what would be printed before the graphic. Print that out.

Then print out the graphic.

The remaining string can be sent after the graphic.

That is the best answer without seeing a sample of what would be in the string and what the graphic is like. It would also be useful of you can put an image of what the printer is outputting.

Comment: I did separate like you said: 1-print half string, 2-print image, 3-print remaining string. And result is 2 parts of string were printed, but image was not. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Combine the text and image and print that into single image. I think thats the best way to achieve it which I have done using Zebra SDK.